# Should I deploy/enable Request Management?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, services, request-management

5 server farm serving 400+ users.

Should we deploy/enable Request Management being that we have no plan of purchasing or using load balancing?

I've dug around but can't seem to find recommended deployment procedures or best practices regarding request management.

I know the process can't be as easy as starting the service on all servers.

Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how many WFEs? are u planning using the network Load balancing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RM need a load Balancer in order to work. Becuase if you have Multiple WFE then how you can you point your SAME DNS to multiple WFEs. It will go only to one server. For Single WFE it is waste.

You can use the WNLB then you configure the RM services.

Here are good Reading

http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2013rm1.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj712708.aspx#proc2

Comment: The article on Harbar net was very helpful I just wish it had part 3. Thanks for your quick reply I will hold off until we determine whether or not load balancing is an option. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Request Management will not help with a lack of Load Balancer. All traffic will still be directed to a single FE. If that FE is unavailable, no users will be able to access SharePoint. There are plenty of 'free' open source load balancers out there (e.g. nginx).

No, I wouldn't enable RM. It doesn't sound like you have an environment to justify it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm going to look into load balancing and then take a look into RM at a later time.

Comment: Honestly, your environment is tiny and doesn't justify using RM period. Even with a couple hundred thousand users in a SharePoint environment, I've not bothered with RM.